# Pure functional code for the sublists of a list

Tags: functional-programming, common-lisp

The code below gives me the list of sublists of a list. Code can still be improved to avoid the use of `append`, right?

```
(defun sublists (alist)
  (labels ((aux (list p r)
             (if (null list)
                 (append r (maplist #'identity p))
                 (aux (cdr list)
                      (append p (list (car list)))
                      (append r (maplist #'identity p))))))
    (aux alist nil nil)))


CL-USER> (sublists (list 1 2 3 4))
((1) (1 2) (1 2 3) (1 2 3 4) (2) (2 3) (2 3 4) (3) (3 4) (4))
```

ideas? This question was posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49019045/pure-functional-code-for-the-sublists-of-a-list originally.

Comment: It's OK for the output to appear in any order, right?

Comment: yes, it is fine.